# Form is not being filled - Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

Having this form:

```
<h3 class="contact-header"><span>Ready to try it</span> GET IN TOUCH</h3>
<%= form_for @contact, url: pages_path, remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class= "flex-row">
    <div class="form-input-spacing">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field  :name, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input-spacing">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="area-input">
    <%= f.label :message %>
    <%= f.text_area :message, rows: 8, cols: 59, required: true, class: "contact-form-text-area",
                            placeholder: "Send us a message"%>
  </div>
  <div class="submit-form">
    <%= f.submit 'Send Message', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to test how it would be filled and then sent with Capybara:

```
scenario "visitor/user sends incomplete contact form" do
    visit root_path #form is in root

    within(".new_contact") do
      # fill_in "#contact_name", with: "Test User"
      # fill_in "contact_name", with: "Test User"
      find("#contact_name").set("Test User")
    end

    save_and_open_page   
  end
```

I have tried `js: true` in the scenario, and both `fill_in` and `find` but when I do `save_and_open_page` nothing is filled.

The reason why I used `.new_contact` is because in the Inspector, that`s the class that the form takes, the` #contact_name`is the id that the input takes and`contact_name`is the label`for`.

If I use `click_button "Send Message"` the button is clicked and a message appears so why is it getting the button but not the input? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save_and_open_page` saves the HTML with the element attributes, not the element's properties. It is really only useful for when you want to see modified page structure (the HTML structure has been changed). When you change the content of a field it changes the value property of that element but doesn't actually update the page HTML (value attribute), so when you save the HTML it won't have the value set.  If you want to see the page as it was use `save_and_open_screenshot`, or just pause your test and look at the browser.

Also `fill_in` takes a locator, not CSS, so it would be

```
fill_in "contact_name", with: "Test User"
```

from https://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#fill_in-instance_method - `The field can be found via its name, id, test_id attribute, placeholder, or label text.` - not CSS